# Increase linewidth in XeLaTex like pdfrender

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I can get the font weight to be higher using `pdfrender` package but it only works in `pdflatex`. When in `xelatex` mode it complains that pdftex is missing. So, is there any way I can produce heavier font weight like this

[image: heavy font from pdfrender]

What I have tried:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

and

```
\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
FakeBold=.2,
BoldFont={ModernMTStd-Bold.otf}, 
%SizeFeatures={Size=14},
ItalicFont={ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf},
BoldItalicFont={Monotype-Modern-Std-Bold-Italic_31158.ttf},
SmallCapsFont={MrsEavesSmallCaps_Regular.ttf},
Ligatures=TeX,
]{Monotype-Modern-Std-Extended_31163.ttf}
```

and

```
\setmathfont{euler.otf}
```

and

```
\setmathsfont{euler.otf}
```

where the fonts specified are in my root directory.But the output is like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Fjg.jpg). I have also used

```
\usepackage[no-math][fontspec]
```

with mathspec but no difference.

Comment: see the fakebold feature in fontspec

Comment: nice. but it makes the main text bold but not the math text

Comment: you specify that on each font separately so you could in principle do the same for the math fonts. Simpler just to pick a bolder font style eg strix2 instead of latin modern or whatever rather than distort the font

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I added the methods I tried to achieve the boldness. Please see if what you are suggesting is included in my attempts or not